# uncaught type error while using fetch in javascript

Tags: javascript, fetch

```
function fetchPage(name){
fetch(name)
.then(res=>{
  console.log(res);
  console.log(res.text()); <<<
  return res.text(); <<<
})
.then(text=>{
  document.querySelector('article').innerHTML=text;
  console.log(text);
});
}
```

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'text' on
> 'Response': body stream already read
> at index.html:30:18

I got an error like text above. There is a problem in the code where i marked "<<<".
Why isn't it working?

Comment: You can only read the response once, as it says. If you remove your debugging log that tries to read `.text()` once too often, it’ll work.

Answer (score 2):

You can only read `Response.text()` once, if you want to `console.log` it, you can store it to a variable first.

By the way, `res.text()` returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#chained_promises). You will get the result of this Promise inside next `.then`.

```js
function fetchPage(name) {
    fetch(name)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            let textPromise = res.text();
            console.log(textPromise); // Promise
            return textPromise;
        })
        .then(text => {
            document.querySelector('article').innerHTML = text;
            console.log(text);
        });
}
```